# How to split values of an column in Pentaho Spoon?

Tags: transformation, etl, pentaho, kettle

I want to create a `Spoon` transformation which will work on multiple values of an column.
Input to my transformation is an CSV file. In that CSV file there's one column named 'Technology' which contains 0 or more values seperated by semi colon as follows.

```
+------------------------------------------------------+

 row_id |   Technology
+------------------------------------------------------+

1       | Cobol ; Db2 ; Jcl ; Vsam ; Cics ; Changeman ;

2       | Oracle ; Sql ; Db2 ; Oracle 9i ;

3       | Windows 2000 ; SQL ;
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have one table in database named 'Technologies' and its schema is as follows :

```
+----------------------+

Technologies

+----------------------+
 id   | technology_name

+----------------------+
```

where `id` column is set to auto increment.

I want to insert values of `technology` column only if that value is not present in `Technologies` table.

Can anyone please tell me

1) Which type of step to be used to split values of `technology` column? 
2) How to insert value only once? For example in `row 1` and `row 2`, `Db2` is repeated but I want to insert `Db2` only once.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Split Fields"  (Under "Transform") to split the contents.

CSV file input --> Split Fields --> rest of transformation

Set the "Field to Split" to "Technology" and set the "Delimiter" to a semi-colon.

Regarding the non-repeating field, my suggestion would be you make the name itself the key to the table. Shift it to lower-case and replace any spaces / special characters with database safe equiv's and then make that the primary key.  You should end up with a table full of only unique instances.

hth